# Why does iBooks Author refuse to open .epub?

Tags: ibooks-author

I have an epub for a hundred-year-old book with the illustrations from the original missing, and no links from TOC to the appropriate places.  Wanting to correct that, I tried to open it from iBooks Author 2.2.  The pub is grayed out in the Open dialogue.  If I select "all files," it is un-grayed, but either way, it cannot be selected.

I don't think the problem is DRM, because the file came from project Gutenberg.  Also, Calibre allows me to convert to PDF and back, but the result still cannot be loaded.  [Talking New Media](http://www.talkingnewmedia.com/2014/10/17/apple-issues-update-for-ibooks-author-adds-in-support-for-importing-epub-and-indesign-files/) claims that this version of iBooks Author adds the ability to open these files.

The "advanced" option to "add to ibooks as proof" also won't open it.  Experimenting, I created new epubs from several PDF originals with calibre, and it won't open those either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iBooks Author only opens iBooks Author projects (.ibooks). You need to create a new iBooks Author file and import the ePub into it. Go to New → New from ePub file….